# Android Test case Intent Response handling if there is no intent in the activity and you just want to write intent only in test class

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-intent, android-espresso

I have 2 activity 1st activity don't have any intent and the second activity have collection of operation like finger capture and device info and many more if you send intent with setAction "capture" then 2nd activity capture the finger and return the response through intent , The intent comes from the another application and we can handle response in the testcase on the another application ,

now the problem is that I want to runTest case 2ndActivity and I want to handle the response means I want to fire intent and get response and perform assertOperation inside my TestClass so I want to Write these intent inside the 1st activity test class so give me a sample project which efficiently handle the response in the testclass remember 1st activity don't have the intent and don't try to write the intent Inside the 1st activity You have to only fire intent and handle response from the 1st activity test class

I have a project which have 2 activity

1 have common views and UI
2 have actions , which activated when another application send intent to this application then according to action it perform the operation and return the response on their on activity result but in my case I want to create intent inside the 1st activity Test class to check 2nd activity intent action are working fine or not ..

@Test
public void TestRDS() {
final String pidOption = "PidOptions";

```
    Intent intentWithData = new Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), RDServiceActivity.class);
    intentWithData.setAction("CAPTURE");
    intentWithData.putExtra("PID_OPTIONS", pidOption);



    ActivityScenario<2ndActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launchActivityForResult(intentWithData);


    intending(hasComponent(".2ndActivity"))
            .respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intentWithData));

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    Intent result = Intents.getIntents().get(0);
    String receivedIntent = result.getStringExtra("PID_DATA");

    Log.e("Response data",""+receivedIntent);



}
```